# In code Go-Ethereum in which file to change the name of the cryptocurrency?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, blockchain-fork, softfork

As I understand it, from the source code of Go-Ethereum, it is possible to fork the blockchain.

Sorry, I'm not an expert on this issue, and if you say to go to Github and change the source, I just won't be able to understand what needs to be changed?

For one project, we need a separate blockchain, functionally identical to Ethereum, but with a different name and symbol of the cryptocurrency.

Of course, there are a lot of files in the source code, and the names need to be replaced by a program, but if you absolutely change Ethereum in all files to Bthereum it can hardly work, I do not think that everything is so simple.

Therefore, I want to ask, in the source code of Go-Ethereum, in which files do you need to manually change the protocol, the name of the cryptocurrency, so that it becomes a separate blockchain, such as Polygon?

P.S. Ethereum is open source, isn't it? He is not a corporate project that is afraid of competition. Then why is there such an impression that the community does not want to help with this issue? Ethereum, like Bitcoin, is not just cryptocurrencies or separate communities, the meaning of open source is not only in the development of one project, but also in the technology as a whole.
Don't think my question is so complicated that you can't answer.

Comment: Me too working on same thing. How far I now it is possible to change currency symbol in Metamask. But it not a solution in code level.

Comment: Then, without changing the code, can you launch a new Polygon network by changing only the genesis file?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't need to change a single line, using a custom genesis file should be enough. The symbol and name are given by third parties from the networkId and chainId, see https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains.

If you want to change the branding that's completely different situation. The word "ethereum", and similarly "eth" are used in many places and it is not easy to change them in a single place. Some of the occurrences are more critical than others, changing them might render an ethereum incompatible blockchain.

go-ethereum is LGPL-3.0 that means code is available for you to make any change you want as long as you follow the license obligations, but being open source it doesn't mean the changes will be easy.

Comment: In the sense that the exchanges of crypto-currencies or metamasks call our network Bthereum and the base cryptocurrency BTH, then for example, the eip155-80 *** .json file with our parameters should be added to chainlist.org?

In other words, wallets and exchanges connect to the network and get the name that they set up?

And what do you have to introduce under the changed brand? At this point, we only need our imi and symbol to be visible during the transaction.
And if for this you need to change the names in the code, then isn't there some kind of config file? To get out of a lot.

Comment: @Ethechain Each centralized exchange has its own policy. If your blockchain is popular enough they may include it on their own, else you have to fill paperwork including name and symbol. Rebranding something like go-ethereum is quite complex, perhaps the minimum you want is to rename the executable, your custom genesis file, etc.

Comment: Well, as I understand it, if you add your genesis file and install a private network with a different port, you will get a separate network, which exchanges and wallets, when added, will call it not Ethereum) Well, this is enough for us for now)
Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

I too need the exact guide like thing for that i just know we can create genesis. Json and I don't know how to generate Mainnetgenesishash and boot nodes key.